# I am merging multi PDFs in a folder using iText 7 using c#. After I have merged them , they all seem to stay in memory. How do I clear them out?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, itext7

I have a dialog box pop up when a button is clicked. I find all the pdfs in that folder and merge them.

Even after merging them all, they all stay in memory.

[image: C# process memory usage]

Can someone please help me fix this issue?
I also need help understanding what Close() is doing. My understanding was that this would be clearing it from memory.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            folderBrowserDialog1 = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            DialogResult = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();

            if(DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBox1.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
                Environment.SpecialFolder root = folderBrowserDialog1.RootFolder;
            }


            if(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath != "")
            {
                
                IList<string> inputFiles = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);

                //destination to make merged file
                string dest = @"D:\PDF-merge";
                string filename = "merged.pdf";

                try
                {
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(dest);
                }
                catch { }


                //creating merge file
                PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest + @"\" + filename));
                PdfMerger merger = new PdfMerger(pdfDoc);
                
                PdfReader reader;
                PdfDocument pdf2merge;

                
                for (int i = 0; i < inputFiles.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (Path.GetExtension(inputFiles[i]) == ".pdf")
                    {
                        reader = new PdfReader(inputFiles[i]);
                        reader.SetUnethicalReading(true);
                        pdf2merge = new PdfDocument(reader);
                        merger.Merge(pdf2merge, 1, pdf2merge.GetNumberOfPages());

                        reader.Close();
                        pdf2merge.Close();
                    }
                }
                
                merger.Close();
                
            }
        }
```

**EDIT**
After merging first folder
[image: firstFolderMerge]

After merging second folder
[image: secondFolderMerge]

Memory usage shown in task manager
[image: taskManager]

Comment: Is there a problem? Can you clearly state the issue this causes?

Comment: I will need the documents to be cleared from memory, because the final application will be used to merge multiple folders containing PDFs into a merged PDF for each folder. Currently, I can merge one folder and all the pdfs are loaded into memory and merged, then if I load up another folder and merge that, all that folders PDFs are also loaded into memory.

Answer (score 0):

Both [`PdfDocument`](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/dotnet/7.1.8/classi_text_1_1_kernel_1_1_pdf_1_1_pdf_document.html) and [`PdfReader`](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/dotnet/7.1.8/classi_text_1_1_kernel_1_1_pdf_1_1_pdf_reader.html) implement `IDisposable`, therefor I'd always use them together with `using` to ensure all resources are freed after using them. Assuming a current C# version you could achieve this with

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < inputFiles.Count; i++)
{
    if (Path.GetExtension(inputFiles[i]) == ".pdf")
    {
        using var reader = new PdfReader(inputFiles[i]);
        reader.SetUnethicalReading(true);
        
        using var pdf2merge = new PdfDocument(reader);
        merger.Merge(pdf2merge, 1, pdf2merge.GetNumberOfPages());

        reader.Close();
        pdf2merge.Close();
    }
}
```

(Of course the declarations of `reader` and `pdf2merge` before the `for` have to be removed.)

Same with `pdfDoc`

```cs
using PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest + @"\" + filename));
```

and maybe the `PdfMerger`, albeit the docs are not 100% clear on that (if the compiler complains about `PdfMerger` not implementing `IDisposable`, well, then it does not.).

Also, the documentation of `PdfReader.SetUnethicalReading` states that they do not take any responsibility if you used this method. What is the reason for you using it? Could it possibly be related to your issue?

**EDIT:**

For root cause analysis, you should consider investing in a memory profile, especially if the code is to be production code some time in the future.

Comment: without using PdfReader.SetUnethicalReading I get the error "iText.Kernel.Exceptions.BadPasswordException: 'PdfReader is not opened with owner password'"

Comment: @JoshuaB So the PDFs are password protected?

Comment: Yeah that must be the case for at least one of the PDFs in my test folder. Atm I am just using a folder of text books that I have

Comment: Okay so you'll leave the `SetUnethicalReading` there for the moment. Did the usings help anything? If this is to be code for production, you should consider investing in a memory profiler.

Comment: It did complain that merger isnt using IDisposable so I have kept that the same, but changed the rest. It didnt fix the issue. Everything still stays in memory. 
I have read that using System.GC.Collect() is bad, but so far thats the only thing that has fixed it.

Comment: The GC would collect anyway, afaik. Can you confirm that the data is not GCed when the GC runs? In your screenshot it did not, as far as I can see.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245543/discussion-between-joshua-b-and-paul-kertscher).

Comment: *"I have read that using System.GC.Collect() is bad, but so far thats the only thing that has fixed it."* - If `System.GC.Collect()` does collect and free the memory, then the memory is not held by your code, garbage collection simply did not kick in. If in production the memory is needed, garbage collection will kick in. You merely should not overdo with parallelization: for some time that memory is needed, and if too many parallel threads need so much memory concurrently, you'll run out of memory.